# curiosity about some properties of Hicksian demand function

Tags: microeconomics

A curiousity arises from one of my homework problem:

> Given u(·) is strictly increasing, continuous, and quasi-concave, show
> that $\textbf{x}^h(\textbf{p}, u)$(Hicksian demand function) is a convex set.

Well I think only quasi-concavity is necessary:
Proof:
$$
\begin{align}
\\ &\forall \ \textbf{x},\textbf{y} \in \textbf{x}^h(\textbf{p}, u_o),  \text{we know}\ u(\textbf{x})\geq u_0\text{, }u(\textbf{y})\geq u_0\text{ and }\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}=\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{y} \text{.}\\ 
&\text{Then, }\forall t \in (0,1), \text{ since u is quasi-concave, we have }u(t\textbf{x}+(1-t)\textbf{y})\geq u_0.\\
&\text{In addition, }\textbf{p}\cdot (t\textbf{x}+(1-t)\textbf{y})=\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}=\textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{y}.\\
&\text{Thus, we know }t\textbf{x}+(1-t)\textbf{y} \in \textbf{x}^h(\textbf{p}, u_o) \text{ and then  }\textbf{x}^h(\textbf{p}, u_o) \text{ is convex.}
\end{align}
$$
Where am I going wrong? It looks like other two conditions are not required for this problem.

If somewhere is not clear, plz tell me. Any advance on it would be highly appreciated.